# Disable sudo user to edit sudoers file

Tags: sudo

I want to disable a user to edit `sudoers` file, so I added a line in sudoers file:

```
Cmnd_Alias BLOCK = !/usr/sbin/visudo, !/bin/nano /etc/sudoers
```

it blocks if a user tries to edit like this:

```
  sudo nano /etc/sudoers
```

but when he's enter to etc:

```
cd /etc
sudo nano sudoers
```

... he can use `nano`, and edit `sudoers`.

how can i solve this?
thanks

Comment: That's not an effective way to manage security on your server, you should really make an effort to read this great book on sudo called Sudo Mastery by MW Lucas - https://www.tiltedwindmillpress.com/product/sudo-mastery-user-access-control-for-everyone/

Comment: This feels like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/203101). Could you explain what you're trying to accomplish here? Why does this user have `sudo` access in the first place? If you don't want them to have full access to your system, don't give them `sudo` access! And if they need it for specific commands, then allow only those commands. I don't think it will be possible to block them from editing a specific file. Even if you manage it, they could still run `cp /etc/sudoers sudoers.copy`, then make their changes in the copy and `sudo mv sudoers.copy /etc/sudoers`.

Answer (score 4):

**From my standpoint...** if you don't want a user to be changing things as `sudo`, **you should NOT be granting `sudo` access in the first place**.  This is for the same reason you don't give your bank account information to Nigerian prince scammers - if they have your information (or access) they will have access beyond what you probably want to grant the individual.

Giving `sudo` access in a way that lets them use any command *except* some commands ("blacklisting" commands) is MUCH harder to implement, and in fact the `sudo` and `sudoers` mechanisms are *not really built* to do this kind of blacklisting in a safe way.

Conversely, giving this hypothetical user `sudo` access for only **some commands** (and not all commands), by specifically specifying the things they can execute as `sudo` on the `sudoers` line, is the proper way to really do this type of restrictions with `sudo` ("whitelisting" commands instead of blacklisting them)

---

This said, if you REALLY want to go this route, then...

In the second method, he's not using the full path.  The command blocks you've initiated here deny access when the **command and arguments** are identical matches.  The utilities are unfortunately stupid and don't actually equate arguments passed in as fully qualified on-disk paths and need to be exact matches to what's being executed.

Add to the list such that you get this:

```
Cmnd_Alias BLOCK = !/usr/sbin/visudo, !/bin/nano /etc/sudoers, !/bin/nano sudoers
```

... **however** there are a trillion ways to circumvent this, so you really should be *whitelisting* access to commands rather than *blacklisting* commands that `sudo`ers are not supposed to use.

Comment: That's still kinda pointless though. The user could still `cd /usr; sudo nano ../etc/sudoers` or `ln -s /etc/sudoers foo; sudo nano foo` etc. And this would mean they can't actually edit `/random/sudoers` file either.

Comment: @terdon Therein lies the problem of giving sudo access.  YOu *really* shoulnd't be giving users sudo access if you don't want them changing things.  Ever.

Comment: @terdon Alternatively, only specify what commands they *can* run as sudo, which is the easier mechanism for restricting.

Comment: Yes, [my thoughts exactly](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1130615/disable-sudo-user-to-edit-sudoers-file/1130618?noredirect=1#comment1872848_1130615) :)

Comment: @terdon Which i now state in teh first part of my answer, that they should go the opposite route or blocking all sudo commands and selectively granting access to the ones they need AND the arguments they need.  Or where possible, `setfacl` to permit editing of certain files  :P

Comment: Exactly, Thomas and @terdon. `sudo` isn't exactly good for _blacklisting_ but works very good for _whitelisting_ and I think that is how it should be used: list all commands that are allowed and not the other way round.

Comment: @PerlDuck this is what I said in the first part of my answer ;P

Answer (score 0):

I usually use the following:

```
username  ALL=ALL, !/usr/bin/su *,!/usr/bin/sudo *, !/usr/sbin/visudo, !/usr/bin/* *sudoers
```

Not sure if I missed out anything. Definitely not fool proof, but the best that I can come out with so far :)

Comment: Not sure if it's me but sudo command is still working so I can always do `sudo -u root -s`