Allow users to execute everything except manage specific service
I have some workers with their own computer. All of them have access in their laptops to root user in Ubuntu. I don't rely on them and I have a critical service that I need to be always running, so I want to remove their access to root to ensure that service execution.
However, when removing root access, may be some other services are impacted to be managed by them. Only that service matters to me, so common users should still be able to execute and manage everything (sudo execution) except the service I talked about.
Do you have any idea about how to do that?
Thank you beforehand.

Ubuntu don't  have root-access enabled pr default. Please describe how users has root-access.

This question is similar to: Block a command from sudo user. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

And also https://askubuntu.com/questions/1130615/disable-sudo-user-to-edit-sudoers-file.

The takeaway from both should be that blocklists aren't effective with sudo. If you block sudo systemctl stop my-very-important.service, nothing prevents a sudoer from doing sudo sh -c 'systemctl stop my-very-important.service', sudo bash -c 'systemctl stop my-very-important.service', sudo python3 -c 'import os; os.system("systemctl stop my-very-important.service")', sudo -i then systemctl stop my-very-important.service, sudo -s then systemctl stop my-very-important.service, etc., etc.
